# Displaying multiple bitmaps in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to display two bitmaps of the same image in the view at different location as shown below, but it's showing only the first one. If I comment out the first one then the other one is displayed.

```
void CChildView::OnPaint() 
{
  // Load the bitmap
  CBitmap BmpLady;
  // Load the bitmap from the resource
  BmpLady.LoadBitmap(IDB_MB);

  CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

  // Create a memory device compatible with the above CPaintDC variable
  CDC MemDCLady;
  MemDCLady.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);

  // Select the new bitmap
  CBitmap *BmpPrevious = MemDCLady.SelectObject(&BmpLady);
  // Copy the bits from the memory DC into the current dc
  dc.BitBlt(20, 10, 436, 364, &MemDCLady, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  // Restore the old bitmap
  dc.SelectObject(BmpPrevious);

  // Draw another bitmap for same image.
  CPaintDC dc1(this);

  CDC MemDCLady1;
  MemDCLady1.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc1);
  CBitmap *BmpPrevious1 = MemDCLady1.SelectObject(&BmpLady);
  dc1.BitBlt(200, 100, 436, 364, &MemDCLady1, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  dc1.SelectObject(BmpPrevious1);
}
```

How to display both the images simultaneously? Please help. Thanks in advance.

P.S: I'm fairly new to MFC.

Comment: Don't create two `CPaintDC` instances. Drop `dc1`, draw both bitmaps onto `dc`. You can also reuse `MemDCLady` (you don't need a second in-memory DC), but that's not the source of the immediate problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to CreateCompatibleDC again for the second bitmap. With the following changes I'm able to display both the bitmaps simultaneously

```
void CChildView::OnPaint() 
{
  CBitmap BmpLady;
  // Load the bitmap from the resource
  BmpLady.LoadBitmap(IDB_MB);

  CPaintDC dc(this);
  CDC MemDCLady;

  // Create a memory device compatible with the above CPaintDC variable
  MemDCLady.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc);
  // Select the new bitmap
  //CBitmap *BmpPrevious = MemDCLady.SelectObject(&BmpLady);
   MemDCLady.SelectObject(&BmpLady);
  // Copy the bits from the memory DC into the current dc
  dc.BitBlt(20, 10, 436, 364, &MemDCLady, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

  // MemDCLady.SelectObject(&BmpLady);
  // Copy the bits from the memory DC into the current dc
  dc.BitBlt(200, 100, 436, 364, &MemDCLady, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}
```